60s movie Hitchcock?
Man (new in town) is at an outdoor auction at a manor house and he is trying to signal a boy to push an expensive vase over (that is currently under the hammer). The boy goes over to it but doesn't do it and the auctioneer confuses the mans push signal (aimed the boy) as a bid signal. The man ends up winning the vase and his love interest sighs a relief to say that she thought he wasn't going to bid on it. (She says this as it's all upperclass show off attitude)
I think this is a 60s film. It's defo colour. I think the guy is a charlatan and not really a millionaire? It may be a Hitchcock movie. 

There is an auction scene in North by Northwest (Hitchcock, 1960s) but I don't remember a sequence like what you describe. Might be worth someone rewatching to check.

Thanks Vastra il bear it in mind but I really don't think that's the one chap.

I didn't think it was, thus the comment and not an answer. Good luck.


Man with a Million (1954)

Two rich British men offer a penniless American a loan, without telling him that the amount is £1,000,000, and this in the form of a single banknote.


One reviewer offers a few more details:

The plot is based on a bet between two brothers that a man with a
  million pound bank note in his possession could live on the fat of the
  land for a month without having to break into it. 
The guinea pig for their wager is Henry Adams, a penniless American
  sailor stranded in London. And, sure enough, he finds this an open
  sesame to food, clothes, hotels and, naturally, society.


From this summary, the events at the auction:

At a reception hosted by the Duchess of Cromarty, Henry meets her
  niece, Portia Lansdowne, who flirts with him and persuades him to
  attend an event related to her aunt's favorite charity, the Home for
  Motherless Babies. 
At the event, Henry unintentionally bids five thousand pounds in a
  silent auction and is later inundated with requests from many other
  charities.


The movie's also known as "The Million Pound Note". Watch that scene you described here.
P.S. He doesn't actually signal the kid to push :-)

Well done rumandwrite - much appreciated my friend.  You're a film genius!

"What a charmingly whimsical gesture" :D

@James - Glad to help. It seems to be a fun movie. Almost like a family-oriented version of "Trading Places" :-)

I thought trading places but then I realised its even more like Brewsters millions ,-)
